# Raw sql query in laravel not working, shows some error

Tags: laravel, rawsql

When I tried to replace laravel query builder with raw sql query, it displays some errors.

Query:

```
$users = DB::select('select * from action_buttons where action_button_id BETWEEN 98 AND 102');
```

On executing the above query the following error displays in a white screen. [image: Screenshot of the error]

> "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

I have added `"use DB;"` at the top. Confused why this error occurs.

Comment: $users = DB::table('action_buttons')->whereBetween('action_button_id', [98, 102])->get();

Comment: Did you config .env file properly and debug configuration? check your logs files

Comment: I don&#39;t know your DB schema and the error. However, my assumption is you&#39;re wanting to see the error displayed and I would guess your environment variable APP_DEBUG or APP_ENV is set to false or production. In a local Dev environment you want debug to be true and env to be local.

Comment: Do not use sql queries directly. DB::raw() is used to make arbitrary SQL commands which aren't parsed any further by the query builder. They therefore can create a vector for attack via SQL injection. https://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries

Comment: As others mentioned this error doesn't look like query related error therefore please check your configurations and this might be helpful too, https://bobcares.com/blog/laravel-something-went-wrong/

Comment: @casper. Thank you. This executes well for me now. I tried the print_r() and it shows the results. But the error still displays below the printed array.

Comment: Please add screenshot of printed array.

Comment: @ casper. I have added the screenshot link at the behind the question  now. Kindly check. Also the fetched results displays a different value for the fieldname compared to phpmyadmin . The results shows  [Home_screen]  instead homescreen. Also the values are also different for this particular field. 0 is displayed in place of 1 while printing the array.

Comment: This is not related to query, did you generate application key ?

Comment: @ No. i did not generate. But there was one key when i downloaded the files.

Comment: Update the key using artisan:  php artisan key:generate and update the APP_KEY entry in the environment file (.env).

Comment: @casper. Thank you. it was resolved.

Comment: Okay great, I've added solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to query, please check your application key. Generate application key using artisan command `php artisan key:generate` and update `APP_KEY` in environment file.

For more info about: `"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."` https://bobcares.com/blog/laravel-something-went-wrong/

Other than that I saw another issue in your query, for best practice do not use sql queries directly.

> DB::raw() is used to make arbitrary SQL commands which aren't parsed
>   any further by the query builder. They therefore can create a vector
>   for attack via SQL injection.

For more info: https://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries

Therefore update your query as shown below,

```
$users = DB::table('action_buttons')->whereBetween('action_button_id', [98, 102])->get();
```

Those changes will sort your problem.